# Zf2 - How to create request to external API with file upload

Tags: rest, request, zend-framework2, client, multipartform-data

I have a Zf2 application that communicates with another Zf2 application through RestAPI calls.

I'm able to communicate between one to another using following code and exchange parameters:

```
 //Prepare request
    $request = new Request();
    $request->getHeaders()->addHeaders(array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
    ));
    $request->setUri($p_url);
    $request->setMethod('POST');
    $request->setPost(new Parameters($p_params));


    $client = new Client();
    //Send request
    $client->resetParameters();
    $response = $client->dispatch($request);
    $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
```

Now, I would like to do the same thing but with a multipart call: Json + files.

How can I do that?
I have tried several solutions from using setFileUpload method of client to writing headers parameters with content-type (multipart/form-data), content-disposition, ... without success.

Along my tests, I used Wireshark to check the request contents. Depending on the solution I tried, I fail in situation with "missing boundary" or HTTP error 405.

Thanks for your help.
Best

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a solution

```
$this->_client->setUri($p_url);
$this->_client->setMethod('POST');

//Prepare for upload
$this->_client->setFileUpload($p_file, 'file');

//Set parameters along with file
$this->_client->setParameterPost($p_params);

//Send request
try {
    $response = $this->_client->send();
} catch ( \Exception $ex ) {

}
```